# How would I turn this into a tail recursion? Haskell

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

I'm trying to get the the index of an element that is in a list.

However the problem I am having is when the element isn't in the list.

I'm thinking that maybe tail recursion is in order, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

```
whatIndex sought [] = -1
whatIndex sought (a:xs) = 
    if sought == a
        then 0
        else 1 + whatIndex sought xs
```

Edit:

When it's not in the list, it should return -1

Example:

```
whatIndex 3 [1,2,3] == 2
whatIndex 3 [0,1,2] == -1
```

Edit:
Was able to get it to work.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of an accumulator?  A worker function (often named `go`)?

Comment: I understand the concept of an accumulator, but not a worker function.

Comment: what is the problem? what would you like to happen when the element is not in the list?

Comment: @KelseyAbreu Often when something may fail (as in, not finding the element) the function will return Maybe.

Comment: Never mind guys. I was able to figure it out on my own. Do you guys mind helping me with something else though? Has to do with case expression in haskell

Comment: @KelseyAbreu Probably best to post a new question :)

Comment: Already done, come help :)?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845898/problems-with-understanding-types-in-haskell

Comment: @KelseyAbreu If you answered your own question, you should post what you discovered as an answer, and accept that answer as correct. The goal of StackOverflow is only in part to answer questions; the other part is to create an artifact that is useful for future visitors with similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you have `Data.List.findIndex`. If you want to write it yourself, there are plenty of ways, e.g.:

```
import Control.Monad

whatIndex x = msum . zipWith f [0..] where
  f i y = if x == y then Just i else Nothing
```

... which returns a `Maybe Int`. If you insist on your -1 hack, add `fromMaybe (-1) $` (which comes from `Data.Maybe`) in front of `msum`.