# problems with understanding types in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

Hey guys so I'm suppose to takes a list of words and returns a list just like it but
with the following substitutions made each time they appear as consecutive words.

One example is `you` and turn it into `u`

I'm given the following:

```
hep :: [Word] -> [Word]
type Word = String
```

now what is giving me problem is that I'm trying to use case expressions so that I won't have to repeat code but I get the following error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
In the pattern: "You"
In a case alternative: "You" -> "u" : hep xs
In the expression: case a of { "You" -> "u" : hep xs }
```

from the following code

```
hep [] = []
hep [a:xs] = case a of 
    "You" -> "u":hep xs
```

Anyone tell me what the problem is?

Edit:

I have added the following code

```
hep [] = [[]]
hep (a:xs) = case a of 
    "you" -> "u":hep xs
    "are" -> "r":hep xs
    "your" -> "ur":hep xs
    "boyfriend" -> "bf":hep xs
    "girlfriend" -> "gf":hep xs
    "great" -> "gr8":hep xs
    a -> a:hep xs
```

Now how would I be able to add a case so that if the list contains 2 or 3 certain words in an order, I could turn that into an acronym?

Ex

```
["By","The","way"] = ["btw"]
```

Comment: That gives me the exact same error just with "You" -> 'u'

Comment: works fine for me. i get an extra "" at the end of the returned list, not sure if that's intended

Comment: Weird, NOW it works for me lol. 
How would I go about adding 2 more cases so that I could compare three words and abbreviate that?

Example:  "By", "The", "way"   would turn into "btw"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to match against a list of a list of Strings, but the type of `hep` is `[Word] -> [Word]`, which contradicts that.  The error message is referring to this fact.

But I'm guessing what you actually want is this?

```
hep [] = []
hep (a:xs) = case a of 
    "You" -> "u":hep xs
    a -> a:hep xs
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me alot. Didn't notice the bracket was missing.

Btw, when I add extra cases I get an error. Imma edit the thread so you can read it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
"By" -> let (y:ys) = xs
        in if y=="The" && head ys=="Way"
              then "btw": hep (drop 2 xs)
              else a:hep xs
```

Although I wouldn't want to write that 50 times in a row. How about this?

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

hep [] = []
hep (a:xs) = case a of 
              "you" -> "u":hep xs
              "are" -> "r":hep xs
              "your" -> "ur":hep xs
              "boyfriend" -> "bf":hep xs
              "girlfriend" -> "gf":hep xs
              "great" -> "gr8":hep xs
              "by" -> matchPhrase 3
              "see" -> matchPhrase 2
              a -> a:hep xs
            where matchPhrase num = 
                    let found = lookup (concat $ take num (a:xs)) phrase_list
                    in case found of
                        Just _ -> fromJust found : hep (drop num (a:xs)) 
                        Nothing -> a:hep xs

phrase_list = [("bytheway", "btw"), ("seeyou","cu")]
```